# Uncaught ReferenceError: eval is not defined at amp-script

Tags: javascript, ampscript

I have added an amp-script to my amp page as described but I am getting the following error message when testing:

`[amp-script] Uncaught ReferenceError: eval is not define`

I believe is related with the `eval()` is used to execute JS loaded async from the bundle generated with webpack (I want to avoid to change here), is possible that `amp-script` doesn't support `eval`?

I made a simple test and with inline JS and got the same error:

```
<script id="scroll-listener" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">
   eval('test');
</script>
```

There is a similar question here: [Why is amp-script throwing an reference error for eval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62312050/why-is-amp-script-throwing-an-reference-error-for-eval) but there isn't any response.

Thanks!

Comment: JavaScript is not Java

Comment: @Andreas my mistake with the tag.